# How Do I Combine Gmail Search Operators?

Tags: gmail, search-operators

I was attempting to create a filter which would delete all emails alerting me that a website updated its terms or privacy policy.

This is the search filter I'm trying to use to accomplish that

```
+updated AROUND 5 {policy privacy terms user agreement}

I've also tried this ↓
+updated AROUND 5 policy OR privacy OR terms OR user OR agreement

and this ↓
+updated AROUND 5 (policy OR privacy OR terms OR user OR agreement)
```

However none of these options appear to work. The only way to get it to work is if I only include one search term after the "around" statement.

Like so:

```
+updated AROUND 5 policy
```

It appears the "around" statement is getting confused. Does anyone know how to combine these operators? It would really help me out.

Thanks!

Comment: Related help article: [Search operators you can use with Gmail | Gmail Help](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en)

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find an answer to this anywhere, but I think I figured it out. So I'm gonna answer my own question in case anyone else needs this.

So basically the "around" operator is not smart enough to combine with the "or" operator (I think, tho I could be wrong). So what you have to do is to use the "or" operator after the "around" operator is applied to each search term.

Like So:

```
(+updated AROUND 4 terms) OR (+updated AROUND 4 privacy) OR (+updated AROUND 3 "service") OR (+updated AROUND 4 +user) OR (+updated AROUND 4 agreement)
```

So if anyone else out there wants to automatically delete terms of service/privacy policy/EULA changes, here is an email filter that works for me.

Thanks!

Comment: This was really helpful, thanks! I would recommend using the curly brace syntax to simplify the query, so yours would become: {(+updated AROUND 4 terms) (+updated AROUND 4 privacy) (+updated AROUND 3 "service") (+updated AROUND 4 +user) (+updated AROUND 4 agreement)}